# how to cast devart.Pgsqlarray to c# list<DateTime>

Tags: c#, postgresql, devart

Simple question but I cant do it. I want something like this:

```
List<DateTime> date_range = (List<DateTime>)reader.GetPgSqlArray("date_array");
```

there is "date_array" data array
[range](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C9lNu.png)

```
List<DateTime> range = new List<DateTime>();
forech(var d in date_range)
{
    range.Add((DateTime)d) 
}
```

also I tried above code it doesnt help; `var d` has type of `PgSqlTimeStamp` and doésnt cast to `DateTime` [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wAOjJ.png)

`System.InvalidCastException: Заданное приведение является недопустимым. в ASP._Page_Modules_Portlets_Contractor_Accounting_tab_Counters_cshtml.Execute() в c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\c36ad8bd\f08f34e7\App_Web_counters.cshtml.403d0071.buf4nvas.0.cs:строка 0 в System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy() в System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage.ExecutePageHierarchy() в System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy(WebPageContext pageContext, TextWriter writer, WebPageRenderingBase startPage) в EleWise.ELMA.Web.Orchard.Mvc.ViewEngines.Razor.CachedRazorView.RenderView(ViewContext viewContext, TextWriter writer) в System.Web.Mvc.Html.PartialExtensions.Partial(HtmlHelper htmlHelper, String partialViewName, Object model, ViewDataDictionary viewData) в ASP._Page_OnTheFlyViews_1815_3f855958bb533eea8d512ad347705771_cshtml.Execute() в c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\c36ad8bd\f08f34e7\App_Web_1815_3f855958bb533eea8d512ad347705771.cshtml.c16a19d8.nu_uhsl8.0.cs:строка 0 в System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy() в System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage.ExecutePageHierarchy() в System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy(WebPageContext pageContext, TextWriter writer, WebPageRenderingBase startPage) в EleWise.ELMA.Web.Orchard.Mvc.ViewEngines.Razor.CachedRazorView.RenderView(ViewContext viewContext, TextWriter writer) в System.Web.Mvc.Html.PartialExtensions.Partial(HtmlHelper htmlHelper, String partialViewName, Object model, ViewDataDictionary viewData) в EleWise.ELMA.Web.Mvc.MarkupRendering.MarkupRenderingService.Render(HtmlHelper htmlHelper, String markup, String language, Object model) в EleWise.ELMA.BPM.Web.Content.Portlets.CustomMarkupPortlet.Content(HtmlHelper html, CustomMarkupPortletPersonalization data)`

## UPDATE

```
PgSqlArray date_range = reader.GetPgSqlArray("date_array");
JArray range = new JArray();
foreach(var d in date_range)
{
   range.Add((DateTime)(d.GetType().GetProperty("Value").GetValue(d)));
}
```

worked for me

Comment: PgSqlTimeStamp [already has an explicit cast operator](https://www.devart.com/dotconnect/postgresql/docs/Devart.Data.PostgreSql~Devart.Data.PostgreSql.PgSqlTimeStamp~op_Explicit.html) so `(DateTime)d` should work. What error did you get?

Comment: System.InvalidCastException

Comment: Which says what? Post the full exception, not just the name or message. Which library  *and version* are you using? Devart's PgSqlTimeStamp *does* have a cast and shouldn't throw

Comment: Post the error as text, not a screenshot

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Devart.Data("5.0.1521.0"), Devart.Data.PostgreSql("7.6.729.0") only way for me to know version is from ilspy disassembly.

Comment: Ok its work like this: ```c# PgSqlArray date_range = reader.GetPgSqlArray("date_array"); 
            List<DateTime> range = new List<DateTime>();
            foreach(var d in date_range)
            {
                range.Add((DateTime)(d.GetType().GetProperty("Value").GetValue(d)));
            }```